# Is it possible to create an entity member that will group other members with OneToMany relations under a single class in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

Server side built with nodeJS + express with nestJS, apollo-server (graphQL), typeorm and postgreSQL.

There is an entity which has oneToMany relations with other entities.
is it possible to group some of them in a class that has no representation in the DB, or in other words - is not an entity?

For example: 
There is an entity `Patient` which has relations with the entities: `PatientAlergy, PatientSymptom, MedicalCondition, etc...`

I would lie to group all of those in a single class `MedicalHistory` so that `Patient` will have a member `medicalHistory`.

Is is possible to give this `medicalHistory` field a deecorator to define it so that the ORM will recognize it?

I tried looking for an answer in typeorm's docs and examples, but didn't find anything useful.

patient.entity.ts:

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
@InputType('patient')
 export class Patient extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field(type => ID, { nullable: true })
  id: number

  @Field(type => MedicalHistory, { nullable: true })
  //@SomeDecorator()
  medicalHistory?: MedicalHistory
}
```

madical-history.dto.ts:

```
@ObjectType()
@InputType('medicalHistory')
// @SomeOtherDecorator()
export class MedicalHistory {
  @Field(type => MedicalCondition, { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(type => MedicalCondition, medicalCondition => medicalCondition.patient, { cascade: true })
  medicalConditions: MedicalCondition[]

  @Field(type => FamilyMedicalCondition, { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(type => FamilyMedicalCondition, familyMedicalCondition => familyMedicalCondition.patient, { cascade: true })
  familymedicalConditions: FamilyMedicalCondition[]

  @Field(type => PatientAlergy, { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(type => PatientAlergy, patientAlergy => patientAlergy.patient, { cascade: true })
  alergies: PatientAlergy[]

  @Field(type => PatientProcedure, { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(type => PatientProcedure, patientProcedure => patientProcedure.patient, { cascade: true })
  procedures: PatientProcedure[]

  @Field(type => PatientSymptom, { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(type => PatientSymptom, patientSymptom => patientSymptom.patient, { cascade: true })
  symptoms: PatientSymptom[]
}
```

I would love to know if there is an option to describe the patient's medical history that way.